# Float divs to both sides

Tags: html, css, css-float

Let's say I have a bunch of divs which have either "left" class or "right" class. Is it possible to make these divs to float on both sides of container like there was a column of "left" divs and a column of "right" divs aligned one under another. Order of divs is random.

I'm not looking for two-column-layout. ;)

Comment: The easiest way is to put them in a containing element and floating _that_.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option since I can't contain these divs in two separate containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See :** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qdZWh/

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: 1px dashed #666
}
.left {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background: yellow
}
.right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    background: #0f0
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: With this approach, the left clears apply to subsequent right-floated elements and vice versa, so it doesn't quite do what we want. Try it with the following HTML to see the problem: ```<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>```